# How to retrieve multiple rows from a SQL Server stored procedure using Pyodbc in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which takes 3 input parameters and can produce multiple rows as output. In fact, it is returning 20 rows in my current case. For instance, if I manually execute the stored procedure from SSMS, I get the following code and partial output, respectively:

Code:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [Coverage-Source].[ReadCoverageMapping]
        @client = N'Capital BlueCross',
        @lineOfBusiness = N'Commercial',
        @distributionChannel = N'Retail'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Output:

```
ID   Attribute   Value      CoverageName
-----------------------------------------     
1      Copay      Yes        Retail Base
2      Copay       No        Retail
.        .         .            .
.        .         .            .
 
Return Value
20
```

Now, while I try to read the stored procedure from jupyter notebook using pyodbc, I get an error

> Procedure or function ReadCoverageMapping has too many arguments specified

I want output something like this:

```
 ID   Attribute   Value      CoverageName
 ------------------------------------------
  1      Copay      Yes        Retail Base
  2      Copay       No        Retail
  .        .         .            .
  .        .         .            .
```

I tried this code:

```
client = 'Capital BlueCross'
lineOfBusiness = 'Commercial'
distributionChannel = 'Retail'
 
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL 
        Server};Server=MyServer;Database=COV_SRCE_TEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
 
 sql = """\
 DECLARE @out nvarchar(max);
 EXEC [cov_srce_test].[coverage-source].ReadCoverageMapping @client = ?, @lineOfBusiness = ?, 
 @distributionChannel = ?, @param_out = @out OUTPUT;
 SELECT @out AS the_output;
 """
 values = (client, lineOfBusiness, distributionChannel)
 cnxn.execute(sql, values)
 rows = cnxn.fetchall()
 while rows:
 print(rows)
 if cnxn.nextset():
    rows = cnxn.fetchall()
 else:
    rows = None
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried using multiple ways, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those batches are different.  Looks like it should be:

```
sql = """\
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [Coverage-Source].[ReadCoverageMapping]
        @client = ?,
        @lineOfBusiness = ?,
        @distributionChannel = ?
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
 """
```

which will output two resultsets, one from the stored procedure, and a second one for the `Return value` which you can probably omit.